# Authentication failed for postgresql server using docker

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to containerization using docker. I just started to learn docker fundamentals like containers, images, Dockerfile, Docker-Compose and volume.

I created a container for PostgreSQL as following:

```
docker run --name to-pg-container -d -p 5000:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=dev -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -e POSTGRES_DB=pg_db -v D:\pg_data\data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:alpine
```

- Using the PowerShell. If I create a container for Postgres with a volume MOUNT I can't access the database using the psql cmd :

  ```
  psql -h localhost -p 5000 -U dev pg_db
  ```
- After even providing the right password it says me:

  ```
  psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5000 failed: 
  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dev"
  ```
- But If I create a container for Postgres without a volume mount, it works fine there are no issues.
- When I asked about this to ChatGPT it says: it could be a permission error and searched for it someone says about the usage with uid gid and I don't have any idea about what it could be.
- Can anyone please help me with this issue? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: If a database system already exists on that volume, it just gets reused rather than reinititialized, which means the password you tried to established gets ignored.

Comment: So what if I need to create a new container with another volume that I used earlier?

Comment: Then you need to use the same user name and password as was used when the volume was originally initialized.

Comment: I actually created a volume using the cmd "docker volume create postgres-volume" where I able find the user name and password here and I used the a host machine directory to mount the volume from there where I able get the name and pass for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need a replication-user in pq_hba.conf.
Like this:

```
local<TAB>all<TAB><TAB>dev<TAB><TAB><TAB><TAB>trust
```

The "dev" user can thus access the database without a password, but only locally!

If you definitely want to access the server remotely, do not use LOCALHOST. Connect to the server by IP, where you can authenticate with password.

Comment: This is my pg_hba.config
`# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256`

Comment: try this:
    host all all all scram-sha-256

->>> replace this line with the next one

    host all all all md5

And use the regular IP address.